# Aeroo Reports: Error while generating the report "Prueba". Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1

Tags: xml, report, odoo

I installed report aeroo modules at OpenERP 6.1, and when i try to print the Sample Report, a get this error:

```
Aeroo Reports: Error while generating the report "Prueba".
Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1
```

I have "aeroo" branch in revision nº 4

I have "aeroolib" branch in revision nº 5

This is the log:

```
2013-04-24 11:48:57,393 12991 WARNING ? openerp.loglevels: notifyChannel API shouldn't be used anymore, please use the standard `logging` module instead.
No LSB modules are available.
2013-04-24 11:48:57,509 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [01]:
2013-04-24 11:48:57,509 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [02]: Environment Information :
2013-04-24 11:48:57,509 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [03]: System : Linux-3.0.0-32-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-11.10-oneiric
2013-04-24 11:48:57,509 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [04]: OS Name : posix
2013-04-24 11:48:57,509 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [05]: Distributor ID:  Ubuntu
2013-04-24 11:48:57,509 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [06]: Description: Ubuntu 11.10
2013-04-24 11:48:57,510 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [07]: Release: 11.10
2013-04-24 11:48:57,510 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [08]: Codename:    oneiric
2013-04-24 11:48:57,510 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [09]: Operating System Release : 3.0.0-32-generic
2013-04-24 11:48:57,510 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [10]: Operating System Version : #51-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 21 15:50:59 UTC 2013
2013-04-24 11:48:57,510 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [11]: Operating System Architecture : 64bit
2013-04-24 11:48:57,510 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [12]: Operating System Locale : es_ES.UTF-8
2013-04-24 11:48:57,510 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [13]: Python Version : 2.7.2+
2013-04-24 11:48:57,510 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [14]: OpenERP-Server Version : 6.1
2013-04-24 11:48:57,510 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [15]: Report generation error!
2013-04-24 11:48:57,511 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [16]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2013-04-24 11:48:57,511 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [17]: File "/home/jorge-hernan/openerp/dev/server/openerp/addons/report_aeroo/report_aeroo.py", line 439, in create_aeroo_report
2013-04-24 11:48:57,511 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [18]: data = basic.generate(**oo_parser.localcontext).render().getvalue()
2013-04-24 11:48:57,511 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [19]: File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aeroolib-1.0.0.RC4-py2.7.egg/aeroolib/plugins/base.py", line 51, in render
2013-04-24 11:48:57,511 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [20]: return self.serializer(self.events)
2013-04-24 11:48:57,511 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [21]: File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aeroolib-1.0.0.RC4-py2.7.egg/aeroolib/plugins/opendocument.py", line 1203, in __call__
2013-04-24 11:48:57,511 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [22]: content = TContent(serialized_stream)
2013-04-24 11:48:57,511 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [23]: File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aeroolib-1.0.0.RC4-py2.7.egg/aeroolib/plugins/opendocument.py", line 809, in __init__
2013-04-24 11:48:57,511 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [24]: self.tree = lxml.etree.parse(StringIO(content))
2013-04-24 11:48:57,512 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [25]: File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2942, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:54187)
2013-04-24 11:48:57,512 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [26]: File "parser.pxi", line 1545, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:79661)
2013-04-24 11:48:57,512 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [27]: File "parser.pxi", line 1573, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:79932)
2013-04-24 11:48:57,512 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [28]: File "parser.pxi", line 1452, in lxml.etree._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:78774)
2013-04-24 11:48:57,512 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [29]: File "parser.pxi", line 960, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:75389)
2013-04-24 11:48:57,512 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [30]: File "parser.pxi", line 564, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:71739)
2013-04-24 11:48:57,512 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [31]: File "parser.pxi", line 645, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:72614)
2013-04-24 11:48:57,512 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [32]: File "parser.pxi", line 585, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:71955)
2013-04-24 11:48:57,513 12991 ERROR ? openerp.loglevels.deprecated.report_aeroo: [33]: XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1
2013-04-24 11:48:57,514 12991 ERROR ? openerp.service.web_services: Exception: (u'Aeroo Reports: Error while generating the report "Prueba".', XMLSyntaxError(u"Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1",))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jorge-hernan/openerp/dev/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 727, in go
    (result, format) = obj.create(cr, uid, ids, datas, context)
  File "/home/jorge-hernan/openerp/dev/server/openerp/addons/report_aeroo/report_aeroo.py", line 713, in create
    return fnct(cr, uid, ids, data, report_xml, context)
  File "/home/jorge-hernan/openerp/dev/server/openerp/addons/report_aeroo/report_aeroo.py", line 656, in create_source_odt
    return self.create_single_pdf(cr, uid, ids, data, report_xml, context)
  File "/home/jorge-hernan/openerp/dev/server/openerp/addons/report_aeroo/report_aeroo.py", line 497, in create_single_pdf
    return self.create_aeroo_report(cr, uid, ids, data, report_xml, context=context, output=output)
  File "/home/jorge-hernan/openerp/dev/server/openerp/addons/report_aeroo/report_aeroo.py", line 448, in create_aeroo_report
    raise osv.except_osv(_('Aeroo Reports: Error while generating the report "%s".') % report_xml.name, e)
except_osv: (u'Aeroo Reports: Error while generating the report "Prueba".', XMLSyntaxError(u"Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1",))
2013-04-24 11:48:58,333 12991 ERROR ? openerp.netsvc: Aeroo Reports: Error while generating the report "Prueba".
Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1
```

Anybody can help me?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

As error show, '<' this starting tag missing in your some or some loop tag please check your code.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. It isn't my code... I've installed report_aeroo OpenERP modules, and when I try to generate a report with aeroolib, I get this error. Any idea? Thank you !